# Browser prompts to add accepted url when IE security is set to HIGH

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, iis-7

I have a web application (.net web app) that work well and across different browers. But this is when browsers Security setting is set to Medium or Low.

I have came up with issue, that when my clients are running IE with Privacy setting set to HIGH, they are asked by browsers to set website in accepted url list.

This is very disturbing. Can any body help me out that what all changes should i make to my site or IIS so that i can bypass IE high security setting.

I have also google a lot on this question, but found none useful answers.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably get more help if you go back and accept previous answers. But with regards to IE - it wouldn't be very good security if there was a way to completely bypass it, would it?

Comment: but why is it prompting my site which runs under https protocol. Also it is not loading icons from font awesome site.

Answer (score 1):

Any method of bypassing the security filtering system sounds an awful lot like **malware** to me.

If a user (or, more likely, their IT department) have insisted on security settings set to **neurotic**, then that's their call. They will have seen an identical warning when they visit CNN or Google online.